# How to get server notification(push notification) to client using vert.x java api

Tags: java, javascript, push-notification, vert.x

I've been struggling from past 4 days to implement push notification in vert.x framework using java(at server side) and javascript(client side). I've been studying example from [this link](https://github.com/vert-x/vert.x/tree/v1.3.1.final/vertx-examples/src/main/java/eventbusbridge).

I am not able to understand what is the significance of **"prefix"** in below line of code.
How to put my custom message to json array, so that it will sent to client as notification.

```
sockJSServer.bridge(new JsonObject().putString("prefix", "/eventbus"), permitted, permitted);
```

And I am also unable to implement client side according to my need. My requirement is get data from database and than **vert.x** server publish that data to n number of clients. What will be the prerequisite for that whole scenario?

In above mentioned link, index.html is there. I debugged this on browser. It successfully connect the server.
One more point is, what is the significance of "/eventbus" in index.html(line no #108)

```
eb = new vertx.EventBus("http://localhost:8080/eventbus");
```

After successful connection with server.Should every client subscribe to server in order to get notification from  server ? I want every client will get notification without any client intervention.

Now, the last point is in below code, what is address? Is it client ip address or server or any other thing.

```
function publish(address, message) {
    if (eb) {
      var json = {text: message};
      eb.publish(address, json);
      $('#sent').append($("<code>").text("Address:" + address + " Message:" + message));
      $('#sent').append($("</code><br>"));
    }
  }

  function subscribe(address) {
    if (eb) {
      eb.registerHandler(address, function(msg, replyTo) {
        $('#received').append("Address:" + address + " Message:" + msg.text + "<br>");
      });
      $('#subscribed').append($("<code>").text("Address:" + address));
      $('#subscribed').append($("</code><br>"));
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Waiting for some help...

Comment: I think nobody is gonna help me.
:(

Comment: do you understand the theory of using any event bus? the idea of address is not vert.x specific, it's just a way to identify messages flowing through the bus. Then you can subscribe many listeners to any kind of message.

Comment: I got the significance of "address".But, I don't know how to get notification at client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function in registerHandler() receive message from server in Json form. You can get your custom message by message.notification where notification is your unique key that is to be set at server side.

Comment: thanks Rahul for your valuable effort. I solved my problem by my itself.